# Runs script repeatedly to api test

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, supertest

I currently have an api test script using supertest + mocha + grunt.

I would like to run this script every 1 minute. How is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use linux cron job or node module schedular

```
https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule
```

TO run your script once in a minute.

Comment: but how can I run with grunt?